# Proper copy of RNG in C++

Tags: c++, random, copy-constructor, mersenne-twister

I have a class containing a RNG:

```
class Sampler{    
private:
    std::random_device rd_;
    std::mt19937 gen_;

public:
    Sampler();
    double sample();
};
```

The class is initialized as follows:

```
Sampler::Sampler() :
                   gen_(rd_())
{}
```

My problem is that I want to use this class (the member function `sample()`) inside another class but I cannot copy the class because `std::random_device` cannot be copied (the copy constructor is deleted since otherwise the same random numbers would be generated).

```
class Foo{
private:
    Sampler s_;

public:
    Foo(Sampler);

};
```

And then:

```
Foo::Foo(Sampler s) :
        s_(s) // does not work
{}
```

While this makes total sense I wonder how one would implement this in order to make it work. I've read that one opportunity would be to construct a proper copy constructor such that every time a copy is made, it gets seeded with a new seed but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You need another random numbers generated in `Foo` that in `Sampler` instance? If not - why not store reference/pointer(smart pointer)?

Comment: Why is `random_device` even a member? You only need it while the ctor is executing, so why are you keeping it alive?

Comment: You're right, so you mean I could also write: `std::mt19937 gen_(std::random_device())`?

Comment: There is a semicolon to much here  `s_(s); // does not work`

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove the `std::random_device` member variable and use temporary `std::random_device` when constructing `std::mt19937 gen_`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

class Sampler{    
private:
    std::mt19937 gen_;

public:
    Sampler();
    double sample();
};

Sampler::Sampler() : gen_(std::random_device{}()) {}

class Foo{
private:
    Sampler s_;

public:
    Foo(Sampler);
};

Foo::Foo(Sampler s) : s_(s) {} // Does work
```

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/gyVRPD).